# Silverlight - Input is not in a correct format. - Which Resource file has this text?

Tags: silverlight, input

Can someone please let me know where the error text 'Input is not in a correct format.' is defined, which is thrown when alphanumeric data is entered in a numeric column in a Silverlight application? Is it in a resource file? I am trying to find out how to display this message in other languages. Please note that this message is different from 'Input string was not in a correct format' exception thrown when a conversion from String to Int fails.

Thanks

Comment: 3 years later this problem still present. This message is buried somewhere in some compiled dll. Anyone solved this mystery?

Comment: For the record - no simple solution, but a way that works is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416658/localize-mscorlib-dll-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your application in Visual Studio; set the exceptions option to break when a CLR Exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried debugging and it is with the call to 
GetResourceFromDefault. I think it is a funciton in a Microsoft DLL based on C++. Does anyone know how this function call works (which resource file is used to search for the key etc.)?

internal static extern string GetResourceFromDefault(string key);

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe the thing that you are looking for. (Look for the answer for the thread. Highlighted in green)
[Silverlight Forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/100615/264212.aspx)