# localize mscorlib.dll Resources

Tags: c#, silverlight, localization, mscorlib

I've opened mscorlib in ILSpy and I see in resources folder:

```
Name, Value
[Format_InvalidString, Input string was not in a correct format.]
```

Is there any way to localize this string?

(Context: silverlight app throws this message whenever incorrect number is entered and it would be much easier to just change this than to write converter and apply it in hundreds of places).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that works is this:

```
public partial class MyEntity        
{
    public string MyField_string
    {
        get
        {
            return MyField.ToString();
        }
        set
        { 
            decimal res = 0;
            var b = Decimal.TryParse(value, out res);
            if (!b)
                throw new ArgumentException("Localized message");
            else
                this.MyField = Math.Round(res, 2);
        }
    }

    partial void OnMyFieldChanged()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyField_string");
    }
}
```

And then bind to `MyField_string` instead of `MyField`.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is localized with satellite assemblies.  You can see those in your Silverlight install location.  On my machine, I've got Silverlight 5 installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.20125.0  Adjust the version number if necessary on yours.

Note the many subdirectories with 2 letter names, "ar" is the one for Arabic for example.  Look in that directory, note the mscorlib.resources.dll file there.  That's the satellite assembly that contains the localized strings, including the exception message strings.  Arabic strings in that specific directory.

And will automatically be displayed on a machine whose user has selected Arabic as his preferred language.  You don't have to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have regional settings set to Lithuanian on my machine, but the error is in English. And also in xap file there are no satellite assemblies, no matter what I try (mostly what's adviced  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). How should I include them?

Comment: Sigh, why on Earth would you leave that out of the question?

Comment: That I tried only after your answer, anyway, should be separate question, you're right